# How to calculate length of tupple not length of the string in python when I am selecting among tupples of various length

Tags: python

I have a switch case statement, in which I pick tupple of various lengths.

```
choices = {'a': ('apple'), 'b': ('peas', 'beet')}
result = choices.get(key, 'default')
print(len(result)) 

#Output key :a gives 5(not 1, this is what I want), b gives 2.
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This is a minor typo. `('apple')` isn't a tuple. You mean `('apple',)` (note the trailing `,`). You're getting the length of the string right now.

Comment: `('apple')` this should be `('apple',)`

Comment: It does. Thanks guys. I am new to Python and didnt not know about the ,